# ASP.NET Trust Level exception

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor

It works fine on my local system. But not on live site. I use this code block for uploding image with ckeditor. I called hosting provider . I must write these codes with trust level medium or high. Hosting firm does not supported trust level full. If I can change trust level full with web.config, it works fine. How can I write or change this code which supported trust level high or medium.

Error : Security Exception

Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.MediaPermission, WindowsBase, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' failed.

```
public static ImageMedia Create(byte[] data)
{
    ImageMedia result = new ImageMedia();
    result._source = BitmapDecoder.Create(new MemoryStream(data), BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.None).Frames[0];
    result._data = data;
    try { result._copyright = ((BitmapMetadata)result._source.Metadata).Copyright; }
    catch (Exception) { }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 3.0 way requires full trust. You could try to get the info from the lower level bitmap

```
Bitmap MyPhoto =
    new Bitmap(@"myphoto.JPG");
PropertyItem[] props =
    MyPhoto.PropertyItems;
foreach (PropertyItem prop in props)
{
    MessageBox.Show(
        prop.Id.ToString());
}
```

Read this article for more details: http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84474/reading-writing-and-photo-metadata/